# Make sure setup is valid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, installshield

I created a setup using InstallShield in VisualStudio 2013. The setup is executed by another application using a process.

What is best practice to make sure that no one manipulated the setup (i.e. replacing the setup file)? What tools do VisualStudio or InstallShield offer for this scenario?

Comment: You may need to be more specific. Is it an exe or an MSI file that you are worried about? How do you think it might be replaced? Is it being downloaded? You need to have a threat model that identifies how the setup might be compromised, then ask how you can deal with them, and to be honest that isn't an install issue - it applies to any scenario where an exe may (say) call a Dll or run another process.

Comment: Sorry for not answering. It's an MSI file. How do you usually handle this situation? I know you can certificate the MSI file and check the certificate in the code. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: A solution is hard to define unless you identify the specific threats you want to deal with. Is physical security in place where this happens? Is an admin allowed to replace it? Is it on a CD or downloaded? Setup tools do not offer solutions because it's not a problem specific to setup tools. How do you protect against loading the wrong Dll that may have been replaced? How does any program that calls another protect against the other being bogus? I'm trying to point out that if you have an issue with an MSI being replaced then you have bigger problems than just the wrong MSI being used.